# Read arabic text file and store to sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am beginner of iPhone developer. I want to read arabic text from arabic.txt file and insert into sqlite database.I used below code but i get two lines for one word like example first line arabic string and second line empty string  so, my array count is getting double.

I have used below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Arabic"
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];

    NSArray *data = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:4 error:nil] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    NSMutableArray *cArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 for(int j = 0; j<[data count]; j++)
    {
        straaa =[data objectAtIndex:j];
        //        NSLog(@"stringnm:%@",straaa);
        ttaa = [straaa UTF8String];
        //        NSLog(@"ttaaL:%s",ttaa);

        NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/.'"" \" "];
        straaa = [[straaa componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        //        NSLog(@"afterchar:%@",straaa);
        [cArr addObject:straaa];
        //        NSLog(@"mystring:%@",straaa);
    }

NSLog(@"arabicCOunt:%d",[cArr count]);

    for (int i = 0; i<[cArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *sqlQuery;
        sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Arabic(Arabic) VALUES ('%@')",[cArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        [dbManager execute:sqlQuery];

    }

}
```

Here, sqlite is working fine but i get array count is double because set value in array alternate line one text and second empty so, double line store in array.

so, first let me know how to arabic text read from arabic text file.and please give any suggestion and source code which apply in my app.

Here i used below arabic.txt file..

```
الكثير سيئة
كيس من العظام
قليلا
قليلا من
بها بعض من المخاطرة
قليلا قبالة
سميكة قليلا
كذبة سافرة
وصمة عار على شعار النبالة واحد
وصمة عار على المناظر الطبيعية
ضربة عن طريق حساب ضربة
صاعقة مدوية
ولدت
فرع
والقيادة العامة لفرع
العلامة التجارية من حرق
وبصرف النظر تولد
ربطة
بدون مصاحبة من الالات الموسيقية
شريحة من كتلة القديمة
فنجان
رحلة ليوم واحد
شيطان من زميل
تقسيم
بيت الدمية
رجل الغرق القبضات في القش
وجه مثل الجزء الخلفي من حافلة
وليمة للعيون
قبل بضعة أيام
عدد قليل من
على بعد خطوات قليلة من الشاطئ
قبل بضع سنوات
غلاية غرامة من الأسماك
برغوث في أذن واحدة ل
ذبابة في مرهم
من باب أولى
صديق في حاجة حقا هو صديق
حياة مثلي الجنس
فتاة في كل ميناء
مصنع تسير
صفقة جيدة
اسم جيد أفضل من النفط جيدة
قدرا كبيرا
عدد كبير من
تل الفول
بيت منقسم على ذاته
مئة في المئة
و100-1 فرصة
الرجل الجائع رجل غاضب
فدية الملك
على غرار
بالصحن
على غرار الحربية COMME على غرار المنتحل
وضع لا
السماح لأسفل
قليلا
وقال لي قليلا الطيور
قليلا
من الصعب قليلا
القليل من العطف يقطع شوطا طويلا
أكثر من ذلك بقليل
قليلا فوق رأسي
السابقة قليلا
القليل من الكثير
تم اتخاذ تحميل قبالة عقله
الخيزران صوتها طويلة
منذ وقت طويل
كثيرا
أكثر بكثير
كثيرا من
رجل
مسألة
شهر من أيام الآحاد
تحولت صفحة جديدة على
عدد من
ع جيانيني
الطاووس في كبريائه
قرش تدخره هو قرش المكتسبة
البعدية
بداهة
لغة البرمجة
رجل الملكية
ربع
لمضغة سريعة
حقيقية الذهاب جالبة
وrivederci
كلمة واحدة
الجواب الرقيق يسكت الغضب
الجواب اللين يصرف الغضب
العقل السليم في الجسم السليم
ولادة نجم
وقد أعلنت حالة الطوارئ
عربة اسمها الرغبة
صبي
ألف مرة
وقت للبكاء ووقت للضحك
برج من قوة
تافه
وعاء يغلي شاهدت أبدا
يوم كامل
أسبوع كامل
سنة كاملة
واحد البرية
صداقة رائعة تطورت
كلمة ذات قيمة كبيرة
عالم من المتاعب
قبل عام
بعد عام من الآن
سنة مقدما
a'asia
قنبلة
تجربة ها
خط اللباس
على بعد واحد
احد في ثون
أ. ب. يهوشع
حروف الأبجدية
a.c.
بعد الميلاد
هجرية
بالنيابة
الملقب
a.l.
صباحا
a.n.wt
a.o.
a.s.s. خريج
a.t.
a.u.
a.w.
أ / ج
أ / د
أ / د المحول
أ / ن
أ / ع
A1
A4
أأ
بطارية حجم AA
AAA
AAAL
AAAS
آخن
AACS
اجي
اجي بوهر
اجي نيلز بوهر
آآآه
العال
عم
aamof
AAR
خنزير الأرض
ذئب الأرض
أرجاو
هارون
عصا هارون
الهاروني
العاص
aaup
أب
من أساسه
أب intestato
أب invito
أب irato
البيضة من أساسها
ابا
ابا ايبان
الأباكا
abacinate
الى الوراء
اللاجرثومي
abactor
طبلية تاج
الجحيم
في مؤخرة كذا
مؤخرة كذا شعاع
حول ممتلكات لشخص آخر
abalienation
أذن البحر
abampere
تخلى
التخلي عن السفينة الغارقة
التخلي عن الأمل
التخلي عن الذات
التخلي عن الذات على الشرب
التخلي عن الذات ل
التخلي عن الذات إلى الحزن
التخلي عن السفينة
مهجور
الأصول المهجورة
تخلى القط
الطفل المهجورة
الأطفال المتخلى عنهم
منجم مهجور
شخص تخلى
المكان المهجورة
الممتلكات المهجورة
حقل أرز المهجورة
زوجة المهجورة
امرأة مهجورة
abandonedly
المتنازل له
المتخلي
التخلي عن
التخلي عن الأمل
هجر
abandonware
حقر
حقر نفسه
إذلال
الخافض
خجل
خجول
abashedly
الخجل
تعذر المشي
abask
abatable
انحسر
انحسار
التخفيف من المطالبة
abater
الحظار عائق من الأشجار مقطوعة يسد به الطريق
abator
abattis
مسلخ مجزر
abature
مجافي المحور
abaxile
العباءة
ABB
أبا
أبا إيبان
abbacy
عباس
العباسي
أباتيال
آبي
دير
دير
آبي
آبي هوفمان
رئيس الدير
رئيس الدير من سوء الحكم
abbotship
ابوت
abbozzo
ابر.
اختصار اسم.
اختصر
مختصر
شكل مختصر
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and the issue doesn't reproduce. That suggests that your problem is your newlines. I suspect you created this list of words on Windows and that the lines end in `\r\n`. `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` will create an empty record for the space between `\r` and `\n`.

Ideally I recommend removing the extraneous `\r` entries and save your input file in unix format. If this is not possible, you should use `compoenentsSeparatedByString:"\r\n"` to split the DOS-formatted file.

Comment: hi all , i want to read arabic words and save into text file in ios application. can you provide any solution how it is posible .

Comment: @jaydev open a new question explaining precisely what you are trying to do (read from where?), what you have tried, what behavior you expected, and what behavior you received.